# Latin char in Javascript regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, boundary, character-properties

How can i inlude the use of latin chars like ČčĆćŠšĐđ in this javascript regexp

```
var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + this.value, "i");
```

UPDATE:

I have this code for filtering checkbox label, but it doesnt work well when there is an input with Č č ć

```
function listFilter(list, input) {
    var $lbs = list.find('.css-label');

    function filter(){
        var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + this.value);
        var $els = $lbs.filter(function(){
            return regex.test($(this).text());
        });
        $lbs.not($els).hide().prev().hide();
        $els.show().prev().show();
    };

    input.keyup(filter).change(filter)
}

jQuery(function($){
    listFilter($('#list'), $('.search-filter'))
})
```

here is a fiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YApax/4/)

Comment: Can you give us an example of runnable code that doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Is this a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258375/latin-charcters-included-in-javascript-regex Also check the link from one of the comments in that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode

Comment: @loganfsmyth Probably something like `new RegExp('\\b' + 'ČčĆćŠšĐđ', "i").test('ČčĆćŠšĐđ')` which returns false.

Comment: Not Latin. Those chars look more like Serbian or Croatian than Latin.

Comment: @Gray Yes, probably. I don’t know any partial bandaide for Javascript’s horrendous Unicode non-handling that doesn’t involve [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/plugins/#unicode), and even that is a far, far cry from the most basic, level-1 compliance with **the published gold standard** for this sort of thing, [***UTS 18: Unicode Regular Expressions***](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/). Because Javascript sucks so bad at Unicode, that forces you to do all Unicode work at the backend in some other more-capable programming language, but that isn’t always possible.

Comment: @Spudley You are mistaken. Those are indeed characters from the Latin script. In particular, they are the characters LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH CARON, LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CARON, LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH ACUTE, LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH ACUTE, LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S WITH CARON, LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH CARON, LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D WITH STROKE, LATIN SMALL LETTER D WITH STROKE, and in that order — provided that this is in Normalization Form C, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your regexp is that the word boundary isn't properly detected with those chars (just like `\w` and `\W` are badly handled with regards to Unicode).

I'd suggest to start with

```
new RegExp('(^|[\\s\\.])ČčĆćŠšĐđ', "i")
```

and to add to `[\\s\\.]` the other chars you may be needing as word boundaries.

If you can't define the expected possible word boundaries, you'd better use a library to produce "Unicode compatible" regular expressions. Some are listed in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode).

Comment: You need to escape backslashes, if you call it this way, but really, the literal is shorter, so I'd better use that: `/(^|[\s\.])ČčĆćŠšĐđ/i`.

Comment: @wvxvw thanks (and +1). I had forgotten the string escaping. I supposed OP had a dynamically provided string to include in the regex, that's why I didn't use a literal.

Comment: @user2406735 I’m not sure that that’s true that “most” regex engines have poor Unicode support, but Javascript definitely earns the *Worst In Show* award there. Go, Java, Perl, Python, and Ruby all to a better job in that regard — and in some cases, a much better one. For Javascript, you should install [the XRegExp Unicode plug-in](http://xregexp.com/plugins/#unicode), which will help.

Comment: @tchrist I'm not sure about "most" (it would be painful anyway to list all engines, especially when you start counting the editor ones) and I agree JS is especially bad on this, so I remove this *"like most engines"*.

Comment: You’re right that it is a big topic to start any sort of enumeration of different programming languages and tools like editors. There’s a summary of Unicode character property support [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) in Part 2’s last column.  The real story is a lot more complex than that, but it’s a good starting-off point.

Answer (score 2):

try with:

```
/^[A-z\u00C0-\u00ff\s'\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]+$/
```

as regular expression.

See the examples below:

```
var regexp = /[A-z\u00C0-\u00ff]+/g,
  ascii = ' hello !@#$%^&*())_+=',
  latin = 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ',
  chinese = ' 你 好 ';

console.log(regexp.test(ascii)); // true
console.log(regexp.test(latin)); // true
console.log(regexp.test(chinese)); // false
```

Glist: https://gist.github.com/germanattanasio/84cd25395688b7935182